# Django REST : Making a custom serializer return proper error message

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the following serializer code:

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
uuid = serializers.CharField(required=True)
number_list = serializers.CharField(required=False)
file= serializers.FileField(required=True, allow_empty_file=False)

class Meta:
    fields = ('uuid', 'number_list', 'file')
```

The issue is that the error dictionary returned when validation fails on any field does not contain the field name. So if I don't pass any argument, I just get an error like this:

> {"error": ["This field is required.", "This field is required."]}

I cannot say which field was missing. When using a `ModelSerializer`, I get field names also in this dictionary, but it's missing in custom serializer. I must be missing something obvious here, but can't get to it.

Comment: DRF by default labels error messages by their fields, are you using any special renderers here?

Comment: Im using these renderers:     
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    ),
All my other views have proper error messages... Only this particular view- which is a custom view having overridden create and destroy method, and using above serializer - is having issues..

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the modified view? It sounds like that might be where the issue is.